# Using a java Deque to keep track of chess states

Tags: java, android

I am implementing an **undo** and **redo** method for a chess app.

So far I have only implemented the undo method by creating a **Deque** of board states, and every time I make a move, I say

```
boardStatesStack.addFirst()
```

then when I want to undo a move, I say

```
boardStatesStack.removeFirst()
```

This acts as a "Last in, first out" data structure which is what I need for the undo move because the last board state you add to the deque is the one that is retrieved when you undo.

However, I want to implement the redo method using the same stack. How can I go about this? The problem is, when I undo, I call removeFirst, which removes the board state so I cant redo because it's not there. I know I can keep track of removed states but I was hoping that this undo and redo method can be achieved by just using one deque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), there is a pop() method that actually removes and returns the first element, you could simply store that element somewhere(another list) and access it again if needed.

Or create this method in your Stack implementation:

```
public Object pop() throws StackException{
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Node temp = top;
        top = top.getNext();
        return temp.getItem();
    } else {
        throw new StackException("StackException on " + "pop: stack empty");
    }
}
```

Note: the above method has been implemented based on the fact that your stack is implemented dynamically, therefore a Node class already exist. You might need to change it if your implementation is different, however it wont be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a queue, use a list and keep your own offset into the list.  When you undo, move the offset down, then when you redo move the offset up.  Of course, if the user makes a new move after undo'ing you'll need to discard any moves on the redo side.